# Java: How do you accept an integer array without using a for loop?

Tags: java

Is it possible to accept an integer array from user without using a for loop?
input will be :

4    //size

1 2 3 4   //array values

```
    String stdin="1 2 3 4";     
    String str[]= stdin.split(" ");
    int st[] = Integer.parseInt(stdin.split(" "));
```

this code does not work though

Comment: `Stream.of(str).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()`.

Comment: Wow thanks , this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without a loop in Java 8 using stream.

Here is what you're looking for:

```
String str = "1 2 3 4";
int[] arr = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
            .map(String::trim).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Goodluck, thanks.

Comment: Thank you!  the split would be for a space right? also you used the (str.substring(1, str.length()-1) to ignore the first input?

Comment: I've made a slight change in the shared snippet.
You don't need to extract out the substring.

And yes, I've splitted it on the space.